# React Table cell value corresponding to radio button selected in another cell

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I want to populate value in different cells of one column corresponding to value of radio button in another column in table in React.
So , there is
Gender column with entry as Radio button male and female and if male is selected it should auto populate male in another cell of different column and if female it should auto populate female . Also want the counter to total number of rows with males and females.

Any help is appreciated.

Link to code : https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-ant-design-demo-forked-nunqd?file=/index.js:0-1123
I need to push value of gender male/female to second column gender selected . Also I need count for total no of male and female selected in table .

Comment: could you share the approach that you have taken / or the code ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-ant-design-demo-forked-nunqd?file=/index.js:0-1123

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I cannot be specific, but performing your radio button select action will create an event that you can then use several different ways.  If you then use that event to change state, any components that use that state will be updated.

[Code Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-flower-019w2?file=/src/App.js)

Perhaps that helps?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-ant-design-demo-forked-nunqd?file=/index.js:0-1123